# Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::store()

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-5.3

**Controller**

```
  public function store( Request $request,$id)
{
    $new = Car::find($id);

    $new->status = $request ->input('field');
    $new->save();

    redirect('home');
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
              @foreach($user->cars as $users)
               {!! Form::open( ['route' => 'user.store', 'method'=>'post','id'=> '$users->id']) !!}
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>{!! Form::label($cars->name)!!}<td>
              <td>{!! Form::label($cars->age)!!}<td>
              <td>{{Form::select($cars->status, ['R' => 'Requested', 'C' => 'Coming', ['name' => 'field']])}} // name is worong but I dont know the alternative 
              <td>{!! Form::submit('Update Profile', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}</td>
              {{ Form::close() }}
```

**Route**

```
    Route::Resource('user', 'UserController');
```

**Problem**

Trying to save the selected value from `status` in Car model. but I get an error about the parameters. Can someone show me where my mistake is? I'm new to Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass additional data to `store` action this way.

You can look at this route by using `php artisan route:list` command. As you can see, it doesn't expect and doesn't pass any data.

So, you need to pass ID in hidden input:

```
{!! Form::hidden('userId', $user->id) !!}
```

And get data in controller with `$request->userId`

Don't forget to remove `$id` from `store()` and `$users->id` from `Form::open()`

Also, correct syntax (with fixed typos) for `Form::open()` is:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'route' => 'user.store']) !!}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But it still gives me `Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::store()`I think the error is somewhere in my controller @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: `$new->status = $request ->input('field');` I'm not confident with this line of code

Comment: it returns the correct user id ( which is the car id )

Comment: Thank you!! Solved passing the id. How about the selected value, how can I pass it in the request with its name ?

Comment: You need to use correct syntax here too. `{!! Form::select('select_list_name', ...` and then get selected element in controller with `$request->select_list_name`. You should read [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) to get familiar with correct syntax for `Form::` clauses.